# SSL Error when requesting with python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to parse a web page when I use the simple `r = requests.get(host)`  it throws a long exception.

I tried the code given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49973802/2013095) but this time it throws a different error

`r = requests.get(host)` Output:

```py
........
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

..............
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...... HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxxxxx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...........
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=xxxxx, port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')")))
```

after using that answer's code :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 841, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Please try the requests.get(url, verify=True) from the suggested duplicate and let us know so we can close as duplicate if necessary.

Comment: try adding this parameter `verify=False`, as `r = requests.get(host, verify=False)`. Check if this works for you.

Comment: I did both and nothing works

Comment: All of those exceptions indicate that `host` is closing the connection on you. You should check whether your data is valid.
Maybe, the request header or body being sent is wrong.